# How to send parameters with POST request to linkedIn api to send message in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, post, linkedin-api

I am testing LinkedIn api to send message. I can sign in with accessToken and also can get contacts from connections, but when I try to send message to one contact id, I get error of unauthorized (401) and fail to send message.

This is the code that I try:

```
NSString *xml;
xml=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><mailbox-item><recipients><recipient><person path='/people/~'></person></recipient><recipient><person path=\"/people/%@\"></person></recipient></recipients><subject>test</subject><body>%@</body></mailbox-item>",contactId,message];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/mailbox"]];
 NSString *newUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?oauth2_access_token=%@", url,accessToken];

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFXMLParserResponseSerializer serializer];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:newUrl]];
[request setHTTPBody:[xml dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-li-format"];

[request setValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

NSOperation *operation = [manager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSXMLParser *parser = responseObject;
    parser.delegate = self;

    if (![parser parse]) {
        // handle parsing error here
    } else {
        // use parsed data here
        NSLog(@"success : %@",parser);
    }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // handle network related errors here
    NSLog(@"error : %@",error);
}];

[manager.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
```

I get this error: 
`Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: unauthorized (401)" UserInfo=0x16e356c0`

I also try the code below:

```
NSString *xml;
xml=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><mailbox-item><recipients><recipient><person path='/people/~'></person></recipient><recipient><person path=\"/people/%@\"></person></recipient></recipients><subject>test</subject><body>%@</body></mailbox-item>",contactId,message];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/mailbox"]];
OAMutableURLRequest *request = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url consumer:consumer token:accessTokenOAt callback:nil signatureProvider:nil];

NSData *myRequestData = [xml dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setHTTPBody: myRequestData ];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-li-format"];
OADataFetcher *dataFetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc]init];
[dataFetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request delegate:self didFinishSelector:@selector(networkApiCallResult:didFinish:) didFailSelector:@selector(networkApiCallResult:didFail:)];
```

Then I get this error :

`"errorCode": 0,
  "message": "[unauthorized]. OAU:77re0739g6qxbx|8439199c-b9b3-48e3-b0f3-9a8dcd51bb8e|*01|*01:1424858697:/0A6nqLIKpAM8cok/sC2WrATUnE=",
  "requestId": "MO733L5NRZ",
  "status": 401,
  "timestamp": 1424858697907`

Why is it like this ? How can I fix it to be able to send message ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also getting same error while trying to call post service for "group-memberships". All suggestions are most welcomed. Thanks in advance